# Ionic gives blank screen when testing the app on real device

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this app.js code in my Ionic App Project.
It gives me a blank screen on start, but only when tested on a real device!
When I use 'ionic serve' to test the app on the browser it works fine!

```
angular.module('orderApp', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    //$stateProvide is like routeprovider in classic angularjs
    //It controlls the pages
    $stateProvider

    .state('categories', {
        cache: false,
        url: "/categories",
        templateUrl: "/templates/pages/categories/index.html",
        controller: "CategoriesIndexController"
    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/categories');

});
```

Comment: Your android device version ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue troubled me a lot!

Turns out to be a weird issue with the **$stateProvider** in ionic or angularjs.
The templateUrl parameter inside the .state should not have a slash in the beginning. Even though this is tolerated by the browsers, it is not tolerated inside the real devices.

So after **removing the first slash from**

templateUrl: "/templates/pages/products/index.html",

and transformed it to:

**templateUrl: "templates/pages/products/index.html",**

in each .state, everything worked fine on the real devices too!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a source js file with an uppercase letter, which was imported lowercase in the index.html. The browser emulation would work fine. The android versions also worked fine on a device if installed with the -lc option. Blank screen only shown in ios/android devices when installed standalone (with no watch to project files).